# Can't connect to openVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I can't connect to openVPN. The error from the `/var/log/openvpn` file is below.
I tried several solutions I found on internet forums but I still can't fix this issue.
Could you please suggest a solution for this.

````
322.194.25.95:50805 WARNING: Failed to stat CRL file, not reloading CRL.
322.194.25.95:50805 VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=CRL has expired: CN=xxx, serial=48224189780147007500459476518371450603
322.194.25.95:50805 OpenSSL: error:14089086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
322.194.25.95:50805 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
322.194.25.95:50805 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
322.194.25.95:50805 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
322.194.25.95:50805 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that your server config has specified a crl (certificate revocation list) file but the openvpn server cannot find it.  Please look for a directive in your `server.conf` configuration file that looks like `crl-verify` and confirm whether or not there is a crl file in the openvpn directory matching that name.

Next, the issue could be that your CRL has expired and you need to generate a new one using `easyrsa`.  You can generate a new crl file using

```
./easyrsa gen-crl
```

And copy the crl to the openvpn configuration directory.